# "Basic conflict" en français?

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

"Basic conflict" semble être un faux ami (ça ne veut pas dire "un conflit basique/peu complexe").

On le voit dans [cette étude](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41562-019-0768-2) :

> Harmful traditions create a basic conflict. [...] This is the basic
>   conflict of applied cultural evolution.

Les propositions de Google translate et de Linguee ne sont pas satisfaisantes :

> Les traditions néfastes créent:...
>
> - un conflit fondamental
> - un conflit de base

Connaissez-vous une meilleure traduction ?

Comment: "Les propositions de Google translate et de Linguee ne sont pas satisfaisantes " Pourquoi et pour qui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selon les contextes …

… en cas de crise temporaire :

> — Des traditions néfastes créent un conflit *majeur*.

… en cas d’analyse ethnographique :

> — Des traditions néfastes créent un conflit *latent*.

… en cas d’analyse historique :

> — Des traditions néfastes créent un conflit *de fond*.

… en cas de référence politique, religieuse ou culturelle :

> — Des traditions néfastes créent un conflit *fondamental*.

Dans l’article cité, on pourrait choisir une de ces propositions de traduction selon l’endroit où l’on voudrait insérer ‘Basic conflict’

Comment: +1 pour conflit de fond ou latent. Merci!

Answer (score 1):

C'et effectivement un faux-ami.

'Conflit de base' est la meilleure traduction.

*You might want to edit your question's body:* Le mot 'conflict' en anglais prend un **c avant le t**.

Comment: Thanks! Mais la phrase `les traditions créent des conflits de base` ne veut pas dire grand chose en français (à mon sens). Elle est vague, au mieux. Mais bon, je ne vois pas ce que ce terme signifie précisément en anglais. (Merci pour la correction, edited ✔ )

Comment: Elle est définitivement vague. Il lui fmanque une suite pour dire à quel niveau, ou concernant quel enjeux, il y a conflit de base, fondamental ou autre.

Answer (score 1):

Si j'apprécie la traduction de *basic* par *de fond*, je suis plus réservé à propos de *conflict*. Pour moi un conflit est le plus haut degré de violence, synonyme de *guerre*.

Je me permet de suggérer des mots plus atténués dont la pertinence dépendra des contextes (il se peut que conflit soit parfois approprié):

- opposition
- tension
- controverse
- désaccord

Answer (score 0):

À priori, et à défaut de pouvoir lire le texte en question pour lequel il faut payer 9 $, *un conflit fondamental* semble possible. *Néfaste* est en revanche un peu léger au regard de ce qui semble être le sujet :

> *Des traditions abominables engendrent/génèrent un conflit fondamental.*

Comment: merci, mais c'était déjà mentionné dans la question (les etudes payantes ne le sont plus grâce à sci-hub + Tor)

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi on devrait refuser "fondamental".

Comment: @Nico Pourquoi mettre ce commentaire à ma réponse ?

Comment: @jiliagre C'était ma réponse à @jinsnow! Je sui tout à fait d'accord avec toi...